# enable phone module on Galaxy Tab A

Tags: 5.1-lollipop

I have a Galaxy Tab A running an intercom app. Problem is that this app uses telephone's default ringtone. To change it, i would need to change telephone's ringtone. Now, this tablet doesn't have the telehpone module enabled. Is there a way I can enable it so that i can access all OS telephone options (like ringtones)?

Comment: Alternative proposal: replace the default ringtone file. You need to have root and/or a custom recovery to do this.

Comment: @AndyYan can you provide more info about this?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your Tab A is not a carrier variant (e.g. AT&T), you can just root the device and replace its default ringtone.

T280 is relatively scarce on development, but nevertheless here are threads ([1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-tab-a/development/rom-samsung-galaxy-tab-7-0-lte-2016-sm-t3455788), [2](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-tab-a/help/resources-samsung-galaxy-tab-7-0-2016-t3431022)) dedicated to it and its LTE cousin (T285) on XDA-Developers. [This post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-tab-a/help/resources-samsung-galaxy-tab-7-0-2016-t3431022/post68859048#post68859048) inside holds TWRP recovery for T280 for rooting and/or replacing. Since I don't have the device on hand, it's up to you to read through the thread, especially the ones after that post, to see how to flash and the precautions (it looks like the steps are more complicated than just flashing it in Odin).

For your purpose you don't actually need root - if you know what the corresponding ringtone file is, just use TWRP's built-in file manager to do the replacement. However, if you don't, it's advised to root so as to make things easier (previewing ringtone files on the fly).

The ringtone file should be somewhere under /system/media/audio. Although modifying audio files shouldn't pose risk, it's still strongly suggested that you make a full backup in TWRP before proceeding.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The tablet is not a carrier variant. I've tried several programs to root the device without success: KingoRoot failed; Mobogenie doesn't detect the tablet; Framaroot says device is not supported. I'll try if i can sobstitute the file in the second way...

Comment: @Mark Did you actually look at the answer? Nowadays one-click root is almost dead. Use TWRP+SuperSU to root.

Comment: Didn't read the link but just the text, sorry. Now, maybe i'm not understanding your reply, but could you tell me how to use the BUILT-IN TWRP FILE MANAGER? From what i understand i should install it but my model is not shown in the link you posted...maybe i'm not expert enough to understand something that may be obvious for you, could you drive me a little further please?

Comment: @Mark What's your model then? Anything other than listed should be carrier custom. With TWRP installed, boot into it, mount /system in Mount, then go to Advanced-FileManager to start exploring.

Comment: The model is SM-T280. It was sold as unbranded and there's no trace of any visible carrier brand in the box or in the software. I tried to boot it in recovery but I can't see the TWRP interface that I see in other tutorials online. Just a screen with the following voices: - reboot system now
- apply update from ADB
- wipe data/factory reset
- wipe cache partition
- reboot to bootloader
- power down
- view recovery logs
- update from cache
- update from external storage

Comment: Ah crap, I forgot there are new Tab A models coming out this year. My previous answer definitely doesn't work then, but I've updated it with what I found now.